# Javascript issues - setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, settimeout

quick question. I'm hoping a JS exeprt can chime in as I'm pretty new to JS.

Trying to set an O'Dometer to spin everytime someone visits a page. But currently everything I try or set has it only spin once, on page load.

Here is an example : (O'Dometer is at the bottom of the page)

[Example of O'Dometer](https://lonebeacondevelopment.com/odfigroup/odonnell-financial-services/)

Currently I have it set as such:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    odometer.innerHTML = 78;
}, 3000);
```

and

```
<!-- Odometr includes -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://lonebeacondevelopment.com/odfigroup/wp-content/themes/odometer-theme-train-station.css
" />
<script src="https://lonebeacondevelopment.com/odfigroup/wp-content/themes/odometer.min.js"></script>


<div id="odometer" class="odometer"></div>

<script> setTimeout(function(){
    odometer.innerHTML = 00;
}, 1000);</script>
```

Can anyone see what I am missing or have coded incorrectly?

Comment: What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: Could everyone please wait for a clarification before answering? SO is not a guessing game, and your guesses are just wrong and not helpful.

Comment: setTimeout triggers once ... your code sets innerHTML to 78 after a 3 second wait after page load ... a page loads once ... so the odometer "spins" once .... to retrigger the odometer, you need to load the page again ... your statement about "every time someone visits a page" vs "page load" makes no sense ... as every time someone visits a page the page is loaded ... once ... not multiple times unless they load the page multiple times

Comment: What's with the apostrophe?

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery('.fusion-fullwidth').waypoint(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    odometer.innerHTML = 78;
  }, 1000);
});
```

Add Above code in your footer OR js file.
100% working...

Comment: You could also put an `alert("Hi")` there, that would work too.